# Different stroke of polygon SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How to set stroke color in SVG polygon with different colors? for example we have quadrangle and have to set 2 stroke red and 2 stroke black

Comment: You can use JavaScript to take an existing shape and overlay lines on top of it; then you can fill the original but color the lines differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw 2 paths. Make one path the red parts of the polygon and the other the black.

Comment: I thought so. But i have to have one svg element

Comment: and how can i fill color beetween 2 paths??

Comment: I don't understand that comment. You were talking about stroke colours in the question so what do you mean by fill?

Comment: Now I want to fill between 2 parallel paths

Comment: Use fill="<whatever colour you want>"

Comment: @RobertLongson you don't understand the comment because you don't understand that he is trying to get a filled-in with polygon with different color strokes. So you solution of 2 paths doesn't address the bit about getting the polygon **filled in** and only addresses the part about the strokes and colors.